# check to see if a email already exists in database

Tags: php

i want people to leave there email for a newsletter and I thought a got it working, and it looks right, but must doing something wrong as it keeps going to the else statment even if there isnt a email in the database!

here is the code:

```
 public function newsStore(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [

            'email' => 'required|max:155', 

              ]);


      $email = $request['email'];

      $result = DB::table('newsletters')->where( 'email', '=', $email)->count();   

      if($result = 0){

              $news = DB::table('newsletters')->insert(
                  [
                     'users_id' => 0,
                     'email' => request('email'),

                  ]);

                 session()->flash('message', 'Thank you for your email!');  

                  return back();

       }else{

                session()->flash('message', 'you have already given your email!');   
                return back();
      }
   }
```

and here is the code on the index page:

```
 @guest
     <form method="POST" action="/sub2">
       {{ csrf_field() }}

   <div class="input-group">
       <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" size="155" placeholder="For our News Letter Email Address" required>

        <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Subscribe</button>
     </div>      
   </div> 
</form>

  @else
  <form method="POST" action="/sub">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

       <div class="input-group">
           <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" size="155" placeholder="For our News Letter Email Address" required>

            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" >Subscribe</button>          
            </div>      
       </div> 
   </form>

 @endguest
```

Comment: `if($result = 0){` should be `if($result == 0){`

Comment: maybe add the laravel tag as well to your question

Comment: @Akintunde007 why? it's not a problem related to laravel

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes i see that. it just keeps things in order. Laravel users might have other suggestions even beyond the issue the OP is facing. just saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`if($result = 0)`{
```

Here you assign a 0 to the $result variable. So is is always false.
Use

```
if($result == 0){
```